# Script to export Outlook rules

Tags: powershell, outlook-2010

Is there are way to script export and import of rules in Outlook 2010?

I am writing a script to remove and recreate user profiles (in Powershell), and as part of this I need to backup and reimport their rules.

Can enumerate through in PS, but I want to create a backup file (as if doing it through the outlook UI) and have that reimported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ed Wilson (aka Microsoft Scripting Guy) wrote up a script for doing this:
[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Tell Which Outlook Rules I Have Created?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/12/15/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-tell-which-outlook-rules-i-have-created/)

He does not state what version of Outlook he is working with but I imagine it works fine with Outlook 2010.